# dig return connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Tags: networking, dns, dig

While trying to dig @8.8.8.8 google.com I'm getting:

> connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Ping works, but I can't dig to any server.
The firewall is off, and port 53 is open (TCP and UDP).

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming but 1) do not use ping to troubleshoot DNS problems 2) try tcptraceroute to port 53 or traceroute -T udp or equivalent to really simulate DNS traffic 3) if you don't get reply it means something is filtering packets between you and remote side.

Comment: Please do this, and put the output in the question: **`dig @8.8.8.8 google.com +noedns +nocrypto +nodnssec +trace`**

Answer (score -1):

If you are ok with iptables and selinux; you must check all network services status once on your machine.

The issue I found is network.service ; was failing on the vm.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).